# phpMyAdmin 4.8 vs 5.0 comparison

Tags: phpmyadmin

[doc](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#which-php-versions-does-phpmyadmin-support) says that since release `5.0`, only `php 7.1` and later are supported. Can you tell me, where I can viw & compare features among `phpMyAdmin` versions? why `v5.0` is so special that it can't be run on php `5.6`?

Comment: It leverages features that are not available in PHP 5.5. And the simple fact is, nobody should be using PHP 5.5 at this point. It went end of life almost 3 years ago and security fixes for it ended almost 2 years ago.

Comment: @Dave I absolutelly agree, just lets forget `5.5` and talk about `5.6`:  many hosting providers still use that PHP version, and users are complaining some of our software because of that. That's why I wanted to ensure why `pma` doesn't support `5.6` (btw, if you post your comments as answer, i'll upvote).

Answer (score 1):

It leverages features that are not available in PHP 5.5. And the simple fact is, nobody should be using PHP 5.5 at this point. It went end of life almost 3 years ago and security fixes for it ended almost 2 years ago.

Comment: thanks, it was nice if there was a list of "those features" available in pma 5.0 that cant work on php 5.6